# domain without www redirects to xampp dashboard

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, ubuntu-18.04

My domain originally had a www (https://www.my-domain.com) i changed it recently to redirect to non www.

Now when i go to `my-domain.com` on my browser, it goes to my localhost XAMPP dashboard (`https://localhost/dashboard/`). and when i turn xampp off, i get a "Unable to connect" on firefox.

I've tried the site on my mobile and my mac, it works fine and points to the server. I've also reinstall xampp on my PC, and still get the same result.

Not sure if this is the issue, but my current .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

and my virtual host on my ubuntu server is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:433>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend/www

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ServerName my-domain.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/html/frontend/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOvereride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what's going on?

My server is running ubuntu 18 on AWS.

Comment: Check your hosts file

Comment: sorry, what host file? @UnbrandedManchester

Comment: What OS is your computer you're on?

Comment: @Insight windows 10

Comment: You can find your hosts file here c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts, open is as administrator and remove the line that has your domain name in (if its there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual problem here is that you have no matching virtualhost set up to handle your new servername.
When that happens on a server, it "redirects" you to first matching virtualhost (which is probably xampp dashboard).

You have probably changed the application and it's .htaccess, but you didn't modify your virtualhost for the domain.

if you DID modify yourvirtualhost, please make sure to restart xampp, otherwise xampp won't consider changes made.

Comment: I updated my question,and included my virtual host code. Any idea what i'm missing? As for the virtual host on xampp, i just reinstalled xampp. so its a fresh new copy

Comment: did you update `hosts` file Unbranded Manchester described? if you cannot connect, it means your computer doesn't know where to find the server

Comment: everything in my `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` is the commented out by default. didnt change it

Comment: vhosts fle is not the same thing as hosts file. 
Please make sure `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` contains a line with `www.my-domain.com`

Comment: & `my-domain.com` (without the `www`)

Comment: yes, you're right. Both www and non-www need to be there. I've assumed it's already there considering it's working :)